# R ggplot 2: how to set geom point alpha based on another variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's use mtcars dataset

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(gear)))
p + geom_point()
```

What I wish to do is, inside geom_point(), I want to set alpha such that it varies based on another column.
For example

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(gear)))
p + geom_point(alpha = cyl)
```

The higher the cyl for that point, the more intense the color. However it seems that alpha doesn't take a variable. Is there a workaround on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you put `cyl` in `aes`. Essentially what is happening here is that you want to be mapping the `cyl` variable. Is this what you are looking for?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(gear), alpha = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: This will do :). Thanks!

Comment: Are there circumstances in which this WON'T work?  I'm using @bjornkallerud solution , my conditional variable is numeric, but not getting conditional alphas in my plot.  Hmm..

Comment: I'm running into the same thing, @Ben